# What is the best optimization for this table and its queries?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hash` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `short_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `content` mediumtext,
  `images` mediumtext,
  `videos` mediumtext,
  `views` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comments_update` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editor_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auther_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `editedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `editedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deletedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `deletedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `deletedfor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `publishedon` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `publishedby_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT AUTO_INCREMENT=91628 ;
```

and some bad queries like this

```
SELECT  id,type , source_id, link, short_link, cat_id, title,
        description, images, views, comments, published, publishedon,
        content, comments_update, editor_id, auther_name, createdby_id,
        createdon, editedby_id, editedon, deleted, deletedon,
        deletedby_id, deletedfor, publishedby_id
    FROM  listings
    WHERE  (cat_id IN ( 98 ))
      AND  (TYPE IN ('1'))
      AND  (source_id IN ('78'))AND (FROM_UNIXTIME( publishedon ) >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) ,
                        1 )
           )
      AND  (deleted =0)
      AND  (published =1)
    ORDER BY  `publishedon` DESC
    LIMIT  10 OFFSET 0
```

and

```
SELECT  id,type,source_id,link,short_link,cat_id,title,description,
       images,views,comments,published,publishedon
    FROM  listings
    WHERE  (title RLIKE 'اليمن|عدن')
      AND  (id != 89024)
      AND  (deleted = 0)
      AND  (published = 1)
    ORDER BY  publishedon DESC
    LIMIT  6 OFFSET 0
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM listings
    WHERE (id > 91152) AND (cat_id = '134')
```

and

```
SELECT  COUNT(id)
    FROM  listings
    WHERE  (publishedon >= '1442963362'
              AND  publishedon <= '1443568162'
           )
      AND  (cat_id IN ('19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '27',
                        '32', '35', '110', '54', '38', '39', '41', '42', '43',
                        '44', '45', '46', '47', '49', '56', '57', '51', '55',
                        '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '102', '95', '96', '98',
                        '101', '103', '104', '105', '106', '124', '125', '130',
                        '131', '132', '133', '134', '135')
           )
```

this query may takes 0.4 sec to be done.  Any in one page it may contain 5 queries like this.  This is very big problem; it causes server load and down time.

This query

```
SELECT *
FROM `listings`
WHERE id = 5455
```

takes 0.0004 sec to be done because its depend on the index of pk

How can I make indexes for columns in the first query?

And many times when I use "show processlist", I see this "Waiting for table level lock" too much and "sorting data".

The application insert/update many rows all the times; how can I solve this?

Comment: The SELECT statement is unreadable; your condition clauses in the WHERE should not be spread over so many lines, but the select-list at the top _should_ be spread over several lines so it can be read without horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is basically:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM listings l
WHERE cat_id = 98 AND
      TYPE = 1 AND
      source_id = 78 AND
      deleted = 0 AND
      published = 1 AND
      FROM_UNIXTIME( publishedon ) >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) , 1 )
ORDER BY `publishedon` DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

For performance, start with a composite index on `(cat_id, type, source_id, deleted, published, publishedon)`.  The syntax is:

```
create index idx_listings_6 on listings(cat_id, type, source_id, deleted, published, publishedon desc);
```

Next, I would suggest re-writing the `where` clause as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM listings l
WHERE cat_id = 98 AND
      TYPE = 1 AND
      source_id = 78 AND
      deleted = 0 AND
      published = 1 AND
      publishedon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBDATE( NOW( ) , 1 ))
ORDER BY `publishedon` DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

And use the same index above.

Comment: is this will make a difference in execute time? and do you mean make an index for these columns? with btree?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE listings ADD INDEX someIndexName (cat_id, type, source_id, deleted, published, publishedon)`

Comment: its work fast only when i removing ORDER BY `publishedon` DESC, any explanation?

Comment: @UnixMan . . . Try using the second version of the query.  I also changed the index so `publishedon` is descending in the index.  That might help MySQL use the index for both the `where` and the `order by` (which is needed for optimal performance).

Comment: can i make other indexed like create index idx_listings_7 on listings(cat_id, type, source_id, deleted, published, views desc); and create index idx_listings_6 on listings(cat_id, type, id desc); and so on, or that is bad

Comment: @UnixMan . . . You can have more than one index on a table.

Comment: any number? what about 10 index? is that bad practice

Comment: what about if i want to order by views?

Comment: @UnixMan . . . I don't fully understand your last two comments.  If you have questions, they are better asked as questions.

Comment: i want to use the last query but using ORDER BY `views` DESC

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot declare an index to be `DESC`; it ignores that keyword and builds an `ASC` index.  However, `ORDER BY x DESC` is still optimizable.

MySQL will use only one INDEX per SELECT.  (Usually).

The optimal index starts with any `WHERE` clause fields with '='.

Query 1:  Already discussed.

Query 2:  `INDEX(deleted, published, publishedon)`

Query 3:  `INDEX(cat_id, id)`

Query 4:  Change `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(*)` and add either `INDEX(cat_id, publishedon)` and/or `INDEX(publishedon, cat_id)`.  It is not obvious which index would be better.  Add both and let the optimizer decide.  As in your other question, it may be beneficial to `PARTITION BY RANGE(publishedon)` and use `INDEX(cat_id, publishedon)` (not the other one).

Consider switching to InnoDB.